# bash shell script 101 - loop in a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, scripting

I am trying to create a script that automates one line of command which is used for archiving selected files to tape and creating a text file with the archived files. a and b are inputs and in the example below and I define them as 03 and 15.

a=03

b=15

tar -cvf /dev/tapedrive file_03 file_04 file_05 .........file_15 > /text_files/backup_file_03-15.txt

the script I came up with is below,

```
#! /bin/bash

a=03
b=15

for (( c=$a; c<=$b; c++ ))
$tt=" ";
do
    if[ ! $c $a ]
    then
        $c="0$c"
    fi
    $tt .= " file_".$c.""
end    

echo tar -cvf /dev/tapedrive $tt > /text_files/backup_file_$a-$b.txt

done
```

it's 'echo' for now instead of 'do' to make sure I get the right final command line. 
I am receiving the error

```
jag5v1.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `$tt=" "'
jag5v1.sh: line 9: `$tt=" ";'
```

I would appreciate any input. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that all you need to say is:

```
a=03
b=15
echo tar -cvf /dev/tapedrive $(seq -f 'file_%02g' $a $b) > /text_files/backup_file_$a-$b.txt
```

Comment: This is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected your code. Try this -

```
#! /bin/bash
a=3
b=15
tt=' ';

for c in $(seq $a $b);
do
    if [ $c -le 9 ]
    then
    c="0"$c
    fi
    tt=$tt" file_"$c
done
echo tar -cvf /dev/tapedrive $tt > /text_files/backup_file_0$a-$b.txt
```